# Query to fetch old data (imported from identical dbs) and new data using joins

Tags: mysql, database, join

Brief: I have imported data from existing applications with identical databases. There a many tables so updating data with new IDs was not a possibility. Existing primary key for each table e.g. *serviceprovider* is *sp_id*. For all tables I added a new primary key *id*. I need to get old and new data (after import is done) from these tables. To get old data I use old primary / foreign keys and compare *database_id* for tables to join from where it was imported. New data only uses new primary key *id*. I know if its a new data by the fact that old primary key has a value *0*.

```
select serviceprovider.* from serviceprovider sp
inner join services ss on ((sp.id = ss.sp_id) AND (ss.ss_id = 0))
OR ((sp.sp_id = ss.sp_id) AND (ss.ss_id <> 0) AND (sp.database_id=ss.database_id))
```

I have constructed this query which gets extremely slow as data is increasing. Initially it worked good but as I import data from old databases it almost stopped working. As you can guess I need to join more table to get complete data. All tables use same mechanism for joining. I am using MySQL. Can the query be re-constructed to get better performance?

Comment: What are the values of *database_id* in the case of new records?

Comment: It goes from 1 to 5. If I have imported data for parent and child tables from database 1 then both will carry database_id as 1 in all their records

Comment: And for non-imported records they are 0 or NULL?

Comment: Databases represent company branches. It goes from 1 to 5. If I have imported data for parent and child tables from database 1 then both will carry database_id as 1 in all their records. In case of new records database_id continue to hold a value between 1 to 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query shouldn't be so heavy, please consider adding an index on all table being joined:

```
serviceprovider(id,sp_id,database_id)

services(sp_id,ss_id,database_id)
```

This should speed up this query.

You can also try to rebuild your query with EXISTS() instead of an inner join :

```
select serviceprovider.* from serviceprovider sp
WHERE EXISTS(select 1 from services ss
             where ((sp.id = ss.sp_id) AND (ss.ss_id = 0))
                    OR ((sp.sp_id = ss.sp_id) AND (ss.ss_id <> 0) AND (sp.database_id=ss.database_id)))
```

Perhaps it will run faster.

**EDIT:** Lets try another approach, two selects and a union instead of this OR condition:

```
select serviceprovider.* from serviceprovider sp
inner join services ss on (sp.id = ss.sp_id AND ss.ss_id = 0)
UNION ALL
select serviceprovider.* from serviceprovider sp
inner join services ss on(sp.sp_id = ss.sp_id AND ss.ss_id <> 0 AND sp.database_id=ss.database_id)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As I mentioned there are more join but this main join seems to be the bottleneck. I have added index for all tables already. Your query runs 3 times slower than the existing one.

Comment: As expected, union solution worked. The key is to split the condition into two. With less data to fetch the difference was less but as I tested it with more data the performance was getting better. I did try union earlier but do not remember the exact version and why it didn't work. Thank you